# Reading out members of a related model in a controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have two models in a relationship.
Level

```
App.Level = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  description: DS.attr(),
  results: DS.hasMany('levelresult', {
    async: true
  })
});

App.Level.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  title: "Lorem Ipsum",
  description: "Lorem Ipsum dollor sit amet",
  results: [100,101]
}];
```

and Levelresult

```
App.Levelresult = DS.Model.extend({
  minutes: DS.attr('number'),
  seconds: DS.attr('number'),
  points: DS.attr('number'),
  failures: DS.attr('number'),
  level: DS.belongsTo('level')
});

App.Levelresult.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 100,
  minutes: 44,
  seconds: 23,
  points: 7,
  failures: 0,
  level: 1
}, {
  id: 101,
  minutes: 12,
  seconds: 33,
  points: 4,
  failures: 22,
  level: 1
}];
```

So I declared a route for the parent(-resource)-template like this:

```
App.LevelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('level', params.level_id);
    }

});
```

Its easy to work with them into the `level/result`-template. Even the related model (as a member of the Level-Model) Levelresult is available within the template (e.a. `{{#each result in results}}`).

Now I want to pick just a single entry out of the related Levelresult's (e.a. "101").
But in the nested route CONTROLLER (level/result as said before) I cant read any member except "id"

```
App.LevelResultController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  getBestResult: function() {

    var results = this.get('results');

    results.forEach(function(result) {
      console.log(result.get('id')); //Output: "100" and "101" --> correct
      console.log(result.get('minutes')); //Output: "Undefined" and "Undefined" --> WHY?
    }

     //... Pick out the best one ...

  }.property('results')


});
```

I don't get it, why reading "id" simply works but other members wont.

Comment: could you set up a ember bin and paste the link ? example - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output